# Getting count of a specific reaction on a message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that will delete messages with a certain amount of `thumbsdown` reactions. I'm having trouble identifying the count of a specific reaction on a message.

Basically, I've created a command that waits for messages and adds them to my `msgarray`. After each message, I want to go through the array and delete any messages with the specified amount of reactions.

This is what I have so far:

```js
var msgarray = [];
const msgs = await message.channel.awaitMessages(msg => {
  msgarray.push(msg);
  for (i = 0; i < msgarray.length; i++) {
    // I'm not sure where to go from here, I want to make an if statement that checks
    // for a certain amount of thumbsdown reactions on the message
    if (msgarray[i].reactions) {
      // incomplete
    }
  }
});
```

This is my first time programming in javascript, so I apologize if this code doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) resolves with a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection), so the `msg` parameter you're using is not a single message, but a Collection of multiple messages.
Also, it would be better to check messages only when they get a reaction, using the [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event, that fires every time someone adds a reaction.
It should look like this:

```js
// this code is executed every time they add a reaction
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  let limit = 10; // number of thumbsdown reactions you need
  if (reaction.emoji.name == '' && reaction.count >= limit) reaction.message.delete();
});
```